# Text Manipulation - Transpose column into rows depending on the value

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, python, csv

I want to write a code to be able to manipulate text on my CSV file which contains the following:

```
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Phi,307200
71w - Ukr,307200
71w - Ukr,51200
71w - Mic,102400
71w - Mic,51200
71w - Jul,256000
71w - Jul,51200
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Ind,50176
71w - Ind,40960
71w - Sin,358400
71w - May,20480
71w - Tha,512000
71w - Tha,972800
71w - Bar,1280000
71w - Bar,102400
71w - Bar,2048000
71w - Upg,358400
71w - Leg,20480
71w - Res,153600
```

I want to gather columns with the same values and put it on their corresponding rows like below:

```
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Phi,307200
71w - Ukr,307200,51200
71w - Mic,102400,51200
71w - Jul,256000,51200
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Ind,50176,40960
71w - Sin,358400
71w - May,20480
71w - Tha,512000,972800
71w - Bar,1280000,102400,2048000
71w - Upg,358400
71w - Leg,20480
71w - Res,153600
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to do this is to use an associative array or hash.  The key for each hash is the first field (I'll call them "ids", for want of a better term), and the values stored for each key will either be a string containing a comma-separated list of values seen for that id, or an array containing the same.

awk:

This awk version uses a comma-separated string because (in awk) it's easier than dealing with an associative array containing an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=" *, *";
  OFS="";
}

{
  key=$1; $1=""; $0=$0;

  if (length(ids[key]) > 0) {
    ids[key]=ids[key]","$0;
   } else {
    ids[key] = $0
   };
}

END {
  for (k in ids) {
    print k "," ids[k]
  }
}
```

In perl, it's no harder (and a lot more useful/flexible) to deal with a Hash of Arrays (or "HoA") than a concatenated string:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my %ids = ();

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /\s*,\s*/;
  push @{ $ids{$F[0]} }, $F[1];
};


END {
  foreach my $key (keys %ids) {
    print $key . ',' .  join(",",@{ $ids{$key} }), "\n";
  }
}
```

---

Output for both awk and perl versions is the same:

```
71w - Ukr,307200,51200
71w - Bar,1280000,102400,2048000
71w - Res,153600
71w - Upg,358400
71w - Sin,358400
71w - Mic,102400,51200
71w - May,20480
71w - Tha,512000,972800
71w - Jul,256000,51200
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Ind,50176,40960
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Leg,20480
71w - Phi,307200
```

Note: the output for both the awk and perl versions is not in any particular order, and will probably come out in a different order every time you run it.  That's because awk "associative arrays" and perl "hashes" (two names for the same thing) are inherently unordered.

You can pipe the output to `sort` if you want.  or, in perl you can use:

```
      foreach my $key (sort keys %ids) {
```

instead of:

```
      foreach my $key (keys %ids) {
```

Also - because we're storing the individual values for each id in an array, in perl it's easy to also sort those values.  e.g. replace the entire `END` block in the perl version with:

```perl
END {
  foreach my $key (sort keys %ids) {
    print $key . ',' .  join(",",sort @{ $ids{$key} }), "\n";
  }
}
```

and the output will be:

```
71w - Bar,102400,1280000,2048000
71w - Ind,40960,50176
71w - Jul,256000,51200
71w - Leg,20480
71w - May,20480
71w - Mic,102400,51200
71w - Phi,307200
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Res,153600
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Sin,358400
71w - Tha,512000,972800
71w - Ukr,307200,51200
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Upg,358400
```

Comment: Wow, I did not think that it was this complicated. I just tested it out and the output is what I am looking for! Thank you!

Comment: it's not terribly complicated.  the only real complicating factor is that you have to read in **ALL** the input before you can print any output - and you need some way to store all the values for each of the "ids" (aka keys) until you're ready to print.

Comment: the other complication is the need to avoid printing an extra comma in the output.  in awk, i checked whether `ids[key]` existed (had a length > 0) to decide whether to append a comma and the data or to set it equal to just the data.   In perl, I just pushed the data into the array (auto-creating it if it didn't already exist) and then used perl's `join()` function to join the array with commas.   lots of text-processing tasks involve splitting data into fields/arrays, doing something to those fields, and then joining them back together again.

Comment: Perfect. both works as intended. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -t, -g 1 collapse 2 < file.csv
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Phi,307200
71w - Ukr,307200,51200
71w - Mic,102400,51200
71w - Jul,256000,51200
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Ind,50176,40960
71w - Sin,358400
71w - May,20480
71w - Tha,512000,972800
71w - Bar,1280000,102400,2048000
71w - Upg,358400
71w - Leg,20480
71w - Res,153600
```

Sorted output using `-s`:

```
$ datamash -s -t, -g 1 collapse 2 < file.csv
71w - Bar,1280000,102400,2048000
71w - Ind,50176,40960
71w - Jul,256000,51200
71w - Leg,20480
71w - May,20480
71w - Mic,102400,51200
71w - Phi,307200
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Res,153600
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Sin,358400
71w - Tha,512000,972800
71w - Ukr,307200,51200
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Upg,358400
```

Options explained:

- `-s` sort input before grouping
- `-t,` use comma as field separator
- `-g 1` group on first field
- `collapse 2` collapse on second field

Have a look at the "collapse" example in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/examples/).

Comment: nice. i often forget that `datamash` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is, or can be e.g by sorting, grouped on the $1 values as shown in your input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
$1 != prev { if (NR>1) print rec; rec=prev=$1 }
{ rec = rec OFS $2 }
END { print rec }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Phi,307200
71w - Ukr,307200,51200
71w - Mic,102400,51200
71w - Jul,256000,51200
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Ind,50176,40960
71w - Sin,358400
71w - May,20480
71w - Tha,512000,972800
71w - Bar,1280000,102400,2048000
71w - Upg,358400
71w - Leg,20480
71w - Res,153600
```

or if you prefer brevity over clarity:

```
$ awk -F, '$1!=p{if(NR>1)print r;r=p=$1}{r=r FS$2}END{print r}' file
71w - Rus,51200
71w - Phi,307200
71w - Ukr,307200,51200
71w - Mic,102400,51200
71w - Jul,256000,51200
71w - Pro,256000
71w - Uni,51200
71w - Ind,50176,40960
71w - Sin,358400
71w - May,20480
71w - Tha,512000,972800
71w - Bar,1280000,102400,2048000
71w - Upg,358400
71w - Leg,20480
71w - Res,153600
```